# Capture argparse message to a variable

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to capture the output of calling `parser.parse_args(...)` to a variable?

I am trying to use this to get the message that is printed on the screen, in case of e.g. missing required arguments.

`__repr__` for the SystemExit exception doesn't contain the help string.

I am interested in obtaining something "error, the following arguments are required: argument_x", and get that in a string.

Comment: You can subclass `ArgumentParser` and implement your own `def error(self, string):`.

Comment: Supporting the above comment with a link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser


class MyArgParser(ArgumentParser):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ArgumentParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.error_message = ''

    def error(self, message):
        self.error_message = message



parser = MyArgParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
args = parser.parse_args()
if parser.error_message != '':
    print('error_message = ', parser.error_message)
else:
    print(args.integers)
```

Comment: it might make sense to store the `error_message` in a member variable of `MyArgParser` -- to avoid global variable.